# In SQL, how do I match specific columns on specific rows?

Tags: sql

This might be hard to describe in the title, here's a sample data:

```
id  pub_type  general_suppl  book_suppl  catalogue_suppl  magazine_suppl
1   book      10             10          0                0
2   book      11             11          0                0
3   catalogue 10             0           10               0
4   magazine  9              0           0                9
5   other     10             0           0                0
6   magazine  8              0           0                10
```

Each of the item is of a specific publication type with a general supplier and a supplier for the type of publication.  `other` items only have a `general_suppl`.  If I want to get all items on supplier value `10`, the following conditions will have to be met:

```
if pub_type == 'book'
    match on book_suppl == 10
elif pub_type == 'catalogue'
    match on catalogue_suppl == 10
elif pub_type == 'magazine'
    match on magazine_suppl == 10
else
    match on general_suppl == 10
```

As you can see above, if `pub_type` falls in `book,catalogue,magazine`, I ignore the column `general_suppl`.

The expected output on supplier value `10` will be:

```
id  pub_type  general_suppl  book_suppl  catalogue_suppl  magazine_suppl
1   book      10             10          0                0
3   catalogue 10             0           10               0
5   other     10             0           0                0
6   magazine  8              0           0                10
```

I can achieve the above by retrieving all the rows and perform filtering at the code level.  Is there a single SQL way to get the above results?  The database design and data are beyond my control, so I can't re-design the DB and will have to work with the above table structure.

Comment: Why do you have separate column for Booksupplier, MagazineSupplier, etc. ?? If each Pub Type can only have suppliers for that specific pubType, this seems unnecessarilly complex and addds little value. In your sample data, no row has two columns populated with different Supplier Ids.  So why not just have a "Supplier" column ?

Comment: @Charles Bretana he already said the design is beyond his control.  Hopefully after he accepts dpmattingly's answer he can throw the designer off a bridge. :-)

Comment: That was my initial observation, I agree it's bad database design but I have to work with this kind of table and data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ugly, but you can throw that logic into a `CASE` structure.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 10 = CASE WHEN pub_type = 'book' THEN book_suppl
                WHEN pub_type = 'catalogue' THEN catalogue_suppl
                WHEN pub_type = 'magazine' THEN magazine_suppl
                ELSE general_suppl END
```

Answer (score 0):

`and` to the rescue!

```
select *
from table
where (pub_type='book' and book_suppl=10) 
  or (pub_type='catalogue' and catalogue_suppl=10)
  or (pub_type='magazine' and magazine_suppl=10)
  or (pub_type not in ('book','catalogue','magazine') and general_suppl=10)
```